# Show that if $4 | (n + 1)$, then there is a prime number $p$ with $p|n$ and $4|(p + 1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $4 | (n + 1)$, then there is a prime number $p$ with $p|n$ and $4|(p + 1)$.

Comment: Supposing otherwise that all prime factors of $n$ were of the form $4k+1$, what would we have for $n\pmod{4}$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Given how frequently the query is posted, I suggest that you save your comment in a text file so that you can copy/paste the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction.

We can manually check a few numbers.

$n = 3,7,11,15$

For each $n$ there as a corresponding $p = 3,7,11,3$ respectively.

Suppose our proposition is true for all $n\equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and $n\le k$

Is our proposition true for the smallest $n >k$ such than $n\equiv -1 \pmod 4$?

If $n$ is prime, we are done.

If $n$ is composite, $n = ab$ such that $a\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $b\equiv -1\pmod 4$

By the inductive hypothesis $b$ has a prime factor $p$ such that $4|(p+1)$